# IPAD IOS 6 not displaying Report in Telerik Report Viewer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc, telerik-reporting

We are having issues where IPAD IOS 6 not displaying Report in Telerik Report Viewer.

We have an MVC ASP.NET application which calls the ReportViewer.

But Report Viewer does not display the report when the 'Preview' button is selected.

Can you suggest how I can display the telerik report in IPAD IOS 6.  Hint: It works in IPAD IOS lower versions than current new version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am quite sure that by now you have solved your problem. However, for other people experiencing the same, the problem  is often caused by the document being rendered within an iframe and the page uses HTML5 DOCTYPE. I have resolved this issue changing this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 .....
```

to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
.....
```

as recommended [here](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/reporting/details/blank-report-in-asp.net-reportviewer-on-ipad-iphone).